# Node.js - How can I wait for something to be POSTed before I reply to a GET

Tags: node.js, post, get, nonblocking

I have 2 clients and one node.js server url - localhost:8888/ServerRequest. The First client GETs from this url and waits for 20 seconds to see if the Second client has POSTed some data for the first client within the 20 second timeout period or not.If the second client did POST before the timeout, then that value is returned to the GET request, else a default value is returned for the GET request. I am not sure what is the best way to implement this. I am trying something like this, but it is not working as desired -

```
function ServerRequest(response, postData , request)
{
    var id;
    if(request.method == "GET")
    {
        id= setTimeout(function( ) 
        {
            // handle timeout here
            console.log("Got a timeout, sending default value");
            cmd = "DefaultVal";

            response.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><list id=\"20101001\"><com type=\"" + cmd + "\"></com></list>")
            response.end()
        },20000);
    }
    else if(request.method == "POST")
    {
        console.log("Received POST, sending POSTed value");
        cmd = postData;
        //Cancel Timeout
        clearTimeout(id);
        console.log(" \n Received POST")
        response.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><list id=\"20101001\"><com type=\"" + cmd + "\"></com></list>")
        response.end()
    }
}
```

Another approach in my mind was to use 2 separate URLs - One for GET Request (/ServerRequest) and the other for POST Request (/PostData). But then how will I pass the POSTed data from one URL to the other if received before the timeout?

EDIT: I think I know now what I exactly need. I need to implement a longpoll, where a client sends a GET request, and waits for a timeout period (the data might not be immediately available to consume, so it waits for 20 seconds for some other client to POST some data for the first client to consume). In case timeout occurs, a default value is returned in response to the GET request from the first client. I'm working on the longpoll implementation I found [here](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/1131), I'll update if I am able to succeed in what I'm trying. If someone can point me or provide me with a better example, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: removed my original code after a more careful reading of the question.

The best solution would probably be [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) the browser will appear to hang waiting for 20 seconds.

Using a library like [socket.io](http://socket.io) you can do this

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);

function postHandler(req, data, res){
        io.sockets.emit("response" , data)
}
```

then client side

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
 <script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
  socket.on('response', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I also want is that if the second client does not POST anything for 20 seconds, then the GET responds with a default value. So I also need some kind of setTimeout, I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You can still implement the timeout with the sockets but with web sockets you dont have the browser hang for 20 seconds waiting

Comment: I am not writing the clients, they have already been written, I can only configure them to GET and POST on my URL and I'm not sure if they are using sockets. Can I still use sockets?

Comment: I might be able to give more useful information if I know why you want a client to wait 20 seconds for a post. What is the end goal here?

Comment: I just added an Edit, hopefully that will add clarity